# Google Sheets run the script in all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to implement the following function on Open sheet but I want to change the tab color on all the sheets. With this function, it allows me to change color only to single tab.

```
function getFirstEmptyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Section A";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var column = sheet.getRange('F:F');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  Logger.log("Row "+ ct);
  var ax=sheet.getRange(ct, 7).getValue();
     if(ax == ""){
        sheet.setTabColor("ff0000")
  } else {
     sheet.setTabColor(null)     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(s => s.setTabColor("ff0000"));
}
```

It hard to tell from the provided code, probably you need this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // get all data
    var col_G = data.map(x => x[6]);             // get column G
    var last_cell = col_G.pop();                 // get last cell of column F

    if (last_cell == '') sheet.setTabColor("ff0000");
  }
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    if (data.pop()[6] == '') sheet.setTabColor("ff0000");
  }
}
```

It will make a tab red if in last row that of the table the cell in column G is empty.

If you have several sheets that you want to change you can filter them by names this way:

```
var names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
sheets = sheets.filter(s => names.includes(s.getName()));

// the rest of a code
```

Comment: You didn't read the function well. I need to execute this if last row of a column is empty.

Comment: There are always empty cells at the bottom of any sheet. So it wouldn't work this way. Show your sheet and I can try to figure out what do you mean.

Comment: I've updated my asnwer

Comment: there are multiple sheets like Section A, B, C... and I want to check onChange or onOpen that whether the last row of the column G is blank or not. If blank then change the tab color of that particular sheet. like using sheet names in array.

Comment: sorry.. by the way it's a trigger

Comment: Did you try my last suggestions? I can't try your sheet since it can not be copied. There is backward direction, so I have no idea how the columns will numerate in this case. And `onOpen()` is a trigger, it will fire every time you open the spreadsheet.

Comment: I want to change the color only from sheet 4 to end. Now here is what this sheet is about. From sheet 4 to end, begining from row 2, col A to F is fetched from another sheet, which is users sheet and column G is my approval checkbox. If i mark it then it will be fetched to other users sheet and they will know now its approved. so whenever a user add data to their sheet, it will be automatically fetched to these sheets. so i want to know if new data are fetched from their sheet on opening this, by changing the tab color of that changed sheet.

Comment: If you need to check only sheets form 4 you can change the loop condition this way: `for (var sheet of sheets.slice(3))`. You can rename the function to `onEdit()` and it will run every time you edit any cell. But it will work quite slow. As for the rest, sorry, I'm giving this up. Too much new details. Hope someone will dare to do it.

Comment: How to stop at 10?

Comment: Something like this `for (var sheet of sheets.slice(3,9))` I think.

Comment: with some modification, i was able to achieve what i wanted using your code. so i will mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to change the tab color for all sheets if the value in column F of the last row of any sheet is blank.  There are other values in that row.  I've include onOPen, onEdit and onChange.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // onOpen is a simple trigger and doesn't need to be installed
  // don't really use e in this scenario
  getFirstEmptyRow();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  // onEdit is a simple trigger and doesn't need to be installed
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if( e.range.getRow() === sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() ) {  
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 6 ) {
      if( e.value === "" ) getFirstEmptyRow();
    }
  }
}

function onChange(e) {
  // onChange is an installed trigger
  // don't really use e in this scenario
  getFirstEmptyRow();
}

function getFirstEmptyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var i=0;
  var sheet = null;
  var value = null;
  var color = null;
  for( i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
    sheet = sheets[i];
    value = sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(),7).getValue();
    color = value === "" ? "ff0000" : null;
    sheet.setTabColor(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english but may be i asked the question in a confused way.

Comment: there are multiple sheets like Section A, B, C... and I want to check onChange or onOpen that whether the last row of the column G is blank or not. If blank then change the tab color of that particular sheet. like using sheet names in array.

Comment: Is "getFirstEmptyRow" an installed trigger?  Or is it called from simple onOpen/onChange trigger?

Comment: installed trigger

Comment: I don't have permission to do anything with your spreadsheet except view the tabs.  But that doesn't matter.  I don't need to see it.  So getFirstEmptyRow is installed as an on Open event trigger?  I think what you want is onOpen change the tab of any sheet in which the last row column F is blank?  You mention onChange but not sure why.  And do you also mean onEdit?

Comment: sorry about that. its just a trigger added on open and on change.